# Textview appearence and disappearence in android

Tags: android, textview

In my application I have to display some 3 edittext views and 3 tex tviews ,Based on some conditions(i.e) if it satisfies some conditions this  should display,otherwise it should not.I have this textviews in xml file.How can i achieve this..Thanks in advance:

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Item" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/itemedit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Price" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/priceedit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:numeric="decimal"/>

    <LinearLayout                                   
          android:orientation="horizontal"          
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <TextView                             -------->TExtview1

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:text="Type" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>        
             <TextView                              --------->TExtview2

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"       
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"  
        android:text="Recurrence" 
       />        

             <TextView                               --------->TExtview3
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"       
        android:text="Start Date" 
       />        

         </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout 
         android:orientation="horizontal" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >

        <EditText                                     --------->edittext1
        android:id="@+id/recccatedit"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  

        />

        <EditText                                       --------->edittext2
        android:id="@+id/reccedit"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

        android:numeric="decimal"
        />

    <EditText                                             --------->edittext1
        android:id="@+id/reccdateedit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"   
        android:layout_gravity="right"
/>
    </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout 
         android:orientation="horizontal" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

                <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btndelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Delete" />


      </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My java class file:

```
if(!reccinc.equals("0"))
            {
                System.out.println("Inside if");
            EditText rec=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reccedit);
            EditText reccdate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reccdateedit);
            EditText recctype=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.recccatedit);

            String recc=null;
            String date=null;
            String type=null;
            db.open();               
            if(!intent.getStringExtra("Recc").equals("0"))
            {
                 Cursor c= db.getReccurenceCount(intent.getStringExtra("Recc"));    
                 startManagingCursor(c);
                 recc=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("increment"));
                 date=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("startdate"));
                 type=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("recurrencetype"));
            }

            rec.setText(recc);
            recctype.setText(type);
            reccdate.setText(date);
            }
```

Comment: Eric i posted that only..I checked that condition to display..But i searched in net but i can't find any relevant answer..So i had a confusion that  i have to do that in code part only,not possible through xml..Thats y i posted here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to make a view disappear from a layout. You can call

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to bring it back again (assuming it has not been removed from the layout).

Answer (score 0):

As you want to show them on particular condition just make your parent layout visibility initially android:visibility="gone" and  if condition satisfies then make that layout visibility to true programmatically so that will be displayed when you want and you can hide that complete layout by setting visibility to gone.

Or if you want to add particular edittext or textview then add and remove them programmatically from your Activity.

you can do for your edittext in following way

initiallly in xml set them visibility="gone"

in your code on particular condition i.e

```
if(!reccinc.equals("0"))
            {
               System.out.println("Inside if");
               EditText rec=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reccedit);
               EditText reccdate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reccdateedit);
               EditText recctype=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.recccatedit);

                after finding them..
                rec.setVisibity(View.visible);
                recdate.setVisibity(View.visible);
                rectype.setVisibity(View.visible);

       and rest of logic goes here..
```

Hope this explanation works for you...

Answer (score 0):

You have to give ids to your textviews

```
 <TextView                               
    android:layout_id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"       
    android:text="Start Date" 
   />
```

And then fetch that in java file

```
TextView textview =(TextView )findViewById(R.id.text);
```

And then on condition do

```
textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Gone will remove your view space from layout

```
textview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Item" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/itemedit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Price" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/priceedit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:numeric="decimal"/>
```

you can have a id for linearlayout as linearlayout1 and set visibility as Invisible

```
<LinearLayout        
      android:id=""@+id/linearLayout1"             
      android:orientation="horizontal"          
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:visibility="invisible">

       <TextView                             -------->TExtview1

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:text="Type" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>        
         <TextView                              --------->TExtview2

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"       
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"  
    android:text="Recurrence" 
   />        

         <TextView                               --------->TExtview3
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"       
    android:text="Start Date" 
   />        

     </LinearLayout>
```

you can have a id for linearlayout as linearlayout2 and set visibility as Invisible

```
  <LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
     android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:visibility=""invisible"
     >

    <EditText                                     --------->edittext1
    android:id="@+id/recccatedit"
    android:layout_width="110dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  

    />

    <EditText                                       --------->edittext2
    android:id="@+id/reccedit"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 

    android:numeric="decimal"
    />

<EditText                                             --------->edittext1
    android:id="@+id/reccdateedit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"   
    android:layout_gravity="right"
```

/>

```
        <LinearLayout 
     android:orientation="horizontal" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Back" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Save" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btndelete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Delete" />


  </LinearLayout>
```

your java file

My java class file:

```
if(!reccinc.equals("0"))
            {
              linearLayout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                System.out.println("Inside if");
            EditText rec=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reccedit);
            EditText reccdate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reccdateedit);
            EditText recctype=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.recccatedit);

            String recc=null;
            String date=null;
            String type=null;
            db.open();               
            if(!intent.getStringExtra("Recc").equals("0"))
            {
                  linearLayout.setVisibility(VIEW.VISIBLE);

                 Cursor c= db.getReccurenceCount(intent.getStringExtra("Recc"));    
                 startManagingCursor(c);
                 recc=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("increment"));
                 date=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("startdate"));
                 type=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("recurrencetype"));
            }

            rec.setText(recc);
            recctype.setText(type);
            reccdate.setText(date);
            }
```